# Uploading image from ESP32 Cam to Spring boot using Multipart

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, arduino, esp32

I am currently trying to upload an image captured on an ESP32 Cam board to a Spring server via HTTP POST. However, I keep getting an error saying

> Required request part 'image' is not present

I have tried multiple solutions across the web but with no success. Here's the arduino code:

```
String serverUrl = "192.168.100.4";
String serverPath = "/identify";
const int serverPort = 8080;
String contentLengthStr = String("Content-Length=");
String crLf = String("\r\n");
String bodyStart = "–-claudiu\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"esp32-cam.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n";
String bodyEnd = "\r\n–-claudiu–-\r\n";

 String sendPhoto() {
  camera_fb_t * frameBuffer = NULL;
  frameBuffer = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if(!frameBuffer) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }
  
  Serial.println("Connecting to server: " + serverUrl);

  if (client.connect(serverUrl.c_str(), serverPort)) {
    Serial.println("Connection successful!");    

    uint32_t imageLength = frameBuffer->len;
    uint32_t contentLength = bodyStart.length() + imageLength + bodyEnd.length();
    Serial.print("Content length: ");
    Serial.println(String(contentLength));
    Serial.println("Posting image");
    
    client.println("POST " + serverPath + " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + serverUrl);
    client.println("Content-Length: " + String(contentLength));
    client.println("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=claudiu\r\n");
    client.print(bodyStart);
  
    uint8_t *fbBuf = frameBuffer->buf;
    size_t fbLen = frameBuffer->len;
    for (size_t n=0; n<fbLen; n=n+1024) {
      if (n+1024 < fbLen) {
        client.write(fbBuf, 1024);
        fbBuf += 1024;
      }
      else if (fbLen%1024>0) {
        size_t remainder = fbLen%1024;
        client.write(fbBuf, remainder);
      }
    }   
    client.print(bodyEnd);
    
    esp_camera_fb_return(frameBuffer);
    
    Serial.println("Response:");
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        String response = client.readStringUntil('\n');
        Serial.println(response.c_str());
      }
    }
    client.stop();
    delay(50);
    esp_camera_fb_return(frameBuffer);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Connection to " + serverUrl +  " failed.");
  }
  return "DONE";
}
```

My Spring Controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class RequestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/identify", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public String identify(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(imageFile.getOriginalFilename());
        FileUtil.saveFile("/images/", imageFile.getOriginalFilename(), imageFile);
        return "WORKS";
    }
}
```

The connection is successful but I can not get a proper response from the server.
Could you please help me find the problem? I have been looking for the past few hours but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with arduino or embedded systems code at all but I have some spring boot experience try something like this on the api resource code I hope it helps and let me know if it works

```
@RestController
public class RequestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/identify", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<String> identify(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile 
    imageFile) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(imageFile.getOriginalFilename());
        FileUtil.saveFile("/images/", imageFile.getOriginalFilename(), imageFile);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("WORKS");
    }
}
```